# Is there any way to detect invalid characters when using ReadHex function in assembly(masm32)?

Tags: assembly, hex, procedure, irvine32, masm32

I wanted to create a program that receives new value if the input value(32-bit hexadecimal) is not correct. Using a ReadHex function was very useful for this, but I have no idea about how to detect invalid characters.

I tried entering invalid characters on purpose to see what that does on `EAX` register, but it just considers invalid characters as 0.

ex) `4FZC` becomes `4F0C`

Comment: Quick and dirty validation of hex digits is convert them to binary (by *ReadHex*) and then back to hexadecimal string and compare (case insensitively)  with input string.

Comment: `ReadHex` works with the standard input, not with a memory buffer. By the time it returns, the hex string is lost.

Comment: @vitsoft: ReadHex reads from stdin and doesn't leave the original string anywhere, so there's nothing to compare with.  It's like scanf, not sscanf.

Answer (score 1):

By the time `ReadHex` returns, there's no more chance to handle the invalid characters. `ReadHex` has no built-in invalid character handling. So either way, you can't use `ReadHex` if you want any kind of invalid character handling.

Consider creating your own version of `ReadHex` on top of Irvine provided `ReadString`.

Read the input (as string), validate the characters, convert from hex to binary. The validation will consist of comparing the ASCII code of provided characters to 0..9, a..f, and A..F. Refer to [the ASCII code table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) to see the digit/letter codes. The digits are 0x30..0x39, lowercase letters are 0x61..0x66, uppercase are 0x41..0x46.

The assembly logic for *validating* the characters would go hand in hand with the logic of *converting* from hex to binary. If you want to convert ASCII characters to binary, you already have to write the logic of checking if it's a number, or if it's an A..F, or if it's an a..f. You have to add a "none of those things" case to the check, and that will be your "not a hex character" logic.

Can you follow up on that?

Answer (score 0):

I normally use a 256 byte lookup table, to translate '0' to '9', 'A' to 'F', and 'a' to 'f' to hex. The remaining entries can be set to a value >= 0x10 to indicate an invalid hex input.